# How to insert a single character between each element in a string to have an array of options

Tags: php, arrays, string

Using PHP, let's say I have this string:

```
$letters = "abcde";
```

I would like to add the character "7" between every character, but so it only occurs once. The result should be an array as follows:

```
$lettersArray = array(
  7abcde,
  a7bcde,
  ab7cde,
  abc7de,
  abcd7e,
  abcde7
);
```

Note: the length of $letters is dynamic from 1 to 12 characters

I have tried using loops with array_splice and str_split with implode, but I can't quite figure out the right logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$letters ='abcdefghi';
$lettersArray = array();
for($i=0;$i < strlen($letters)+1; $i++) {
    $new = substr($letters, 0, $i);
    $new .= '7';
    $new .= substr($letters, $i);
    $lettersArray[] = $new;
}
print_r($lettersArray);
```

What this does is take each element of the array, and inserts the letter 7 in an incrementing fashion into the array item.

Comment: Worked great. I finally (after 1 hour trial and error) also found a similar solution that I will post below. Thanks.

Comment: I ran all 4 solutions posted here on the same webpage at the same time with timers attached to each one. Indranil and nishantagarwal who both use string substitution instead of arrays ran in less than half the time as the other array based solutions. Good note to know for the future. With that in mind, I will be changing my code to something close to Indranil's. Thanks again for the various solutions to the same problem.

Comment: FYI, the code is now running live on http://scrabblehints.com when you use a "?" for a blank tile. This code puts a blank (actually a "_" i the SQL command) between the combinations of you search for. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple , do like this

```
echo implode("+", str_split('vimal'));           // OUTPUT : v+i+m+a+l
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
$split_letters = str_split($letters);
$letters_array = array();

for($i = 0; $i <= count($split_letters); $i++) {

   $start_letters = array_slice($split_letters, 0, $i);

   $end_letters = array_slice($split_letters, $i);

   $letters_array[] = array_merge($start_letters, array(7), $end_letters); 

}
```

Comment: my apologies. fixed. `count($letters)` should be `count($split_letters)`. And this codepad thing is awesome!

Comment: Works great too. Thanks. Very similar to my solution that took me 2+ hours to get to. I added implode(array_merge(...)) so the final letters_array contained strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$letters = "abcde";
$character = "7";
$len = strlen($letters);
$lettersArray = array();

for($i=0; $i <= $len; $i++)
{
    $temp = "";
    $temp = substr($letters, 0, $i) . $character . substr($letters, $i);
    $lettersArray[] = $temp;
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/gFByJb

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours (including writing this question) I finally also came up with a solution that is similar to the others posted here. It's posted below, but I prefer other solutions posted here.

```
$letters = "abcde";
$results = array(); 
$lettersArray = str_split($letters);
foreach ($lettersArray as $key => $lets) {
    $tempArray = $lettersArray;
    array_splice($tempArray, $key, 0, "7");
    $results[] = implode($tempArray);
}
$results[] = $letters . "7"; //required for the final combination
print_r($results);
```